# What word would be used to describe the action a person would do when taking a story and changing the story to fit their needs?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing an essay and I cannot for the life of me think of the word that is used to describe this action. It would do me a great deal of good if you guys can help me remember the word.

Comment: If it is a preexisting story, you may "adapt" it e.g. for motion picture.  If it is only a story type, you may "improvise" the fine points as you go along.

Comment: By 'story', do you mean a creative work of fiction, or a narrative of true events?  If the latter, you might be looking for an *"interpretation"*

Comment: You haven't defined this clearly. What do you mean by "...changing...to fit their needs..."?  What needs are you talking about? A criminal who wanted to plead innocence might use 'fabrication', a comedian might use 'embellishment', etc.  There are dozens of possibilities. Please give us some context. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Embellish

> Make (a statement or story) more interesting or entertaining by adding extra details, especially ones that are not true.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **twist**.

twist: to distort the meaning or form of; pervert ([Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/twist))

*Heth took the story and [twisted](http://www.gdg.org/Research/Authored%20Items/hartwig.html) it to protect himself.*

Depending on context, **tamper with** could also fit the bill.

*The Bosnians had first done nasty things to the Serbs and the western world has [tampered with](http://www.historynewsnetwork.org/blog/52572) the story so as to justify armed intervention...*

tamper (with): to make changes in something, especially in order to falsify. ([Dictionary Reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tamper))

Answer (score 0):

[Adapt](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adapt) is defined in Merriam-Webster:

> : to change (a movie, book, play, etc.) so that it can be presented in
>   another form

[Adaptation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adaptation):

> the process of changing to fit some purpose or situation : the process
>   of adapting

Answer (score 0):

I think the word is ***transliteration*** (verb ***transliterate***). But look at its synonyms - they are various e.g. ***interpolation*** (verb ***interpolate***).

Answer (score 0):

consider this sentence: he laid the story on a Procrustean bed. The term Procrustean bed refers to trimming or stretching to fit a certain desire or standard.

Answer (score 0):

**Revised**

verb (used with object), revised, revising.
1. to amend or alter: to revise one's opinion.
2. to alter something already written or printed, in order to make corrections, improve, or update:
to revise a manuscript.

Comment: Adding to this answer, if the OP's "story" is an historical event, then "historical revisionism" is a common term. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_revisionism